# Why is my for loop not incrementing in a function?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to grab the cursor position and store it in `int x[]` for the x coordinate and `int y[]` for the y coordinate.

However, when I pass the arrays to a function with a for loop that is supposed to set the mouse's coordinates to the ones stored in the array, incrementing through each element, the for loop does not seem to increment i.

```
void click(clock_t &st, int x[], int y[]);

int x[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int y[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int amtToggled = 0; //Controlled by hotkeys utilizing GetAsyncKeyState.

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) && !inMenu)
{
    GetCursorPos(&n);

    x[0] = n.x;
    y[0] = n.y;

    uWindow = true;
    Sleep(150);
}

void click(clock_t &st, int x[], int y[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amtToggled; i++)
    {
        float te = clock() - st;
        if ((te / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= (aDelay / 1000))
        {
            LOG(i);
            SetCursorPos(x[i], y[i]);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, q, z, 0, 0);
            Sleep(50);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, q, z, 0, 0);
            Sleep(50);
            st = clock();
        }
    }
}
```

The for loop should "iterate" through the array and set the mouse position to the coordinates stored in each x and y corresponding element of the array increasing the element position each iteration. Instead i just stays 0.

Edit #1: Full Source: https://pastebin.com/HdaaBbKm

Comment: Too many unknowns. For the beginning, can you print values of `x, y, amToggled, aDelay` in the beginning of `click`? Most likely the reason is that `aDelay < 1000`, therefore `aDelay / 1000 = 0`, and the condition is always true. Better, just provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I could have misundertood your question but x is a array whose contents are zero, and I cant see where you are changing it, so, x[i], with i = 0, 1, 2, ... will return 0

Comment: Is this complete program? Where is 'amtToggled' being modified? Checking condition in the for loop is i < amtToggled. So you are comparing 0 < 0. The control will never go inside the for loop.

Comment: My apologies. I am changing the array contents with `GetCursorPos(&n);` and `x[0] = n.x;`, `y[0] = n.y;`. The function runs throughout executing each mouse click and I can confirm the contents of the array are being changed properly.

Comment: Sorry I did not want to flood the post with code that may be useless. Here is the full source: https://pastebin.com/HdaaBbKm

Comment: Assume that there is no for loop. If you run loop body with, say, `SetCursorPos(100, 100);` instead of `SetCursorPos(x[i], y[i]);`, does it change mouse position?

Comment: amToggled value must not be changing

Comment: @dyukha if you mean just running SetCursorPos without a for loop then yes it does set the position

Comment: Can you show us values as I asked in the first comment?

Comment: @VidorVistrom After outputting amtToggled to the console and checking it appears to be increasing and decreasing as intended.

Comment: Do you have a debugger? Just step through the code and I'm sure you'll figure this out in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @dyukha The values of the `x and y` arrays are set to 0 by default then defined by user input later in the code to the x and y position of the cursor. `amtToggled` increments and decrements when the user toggles a feature by pressing (1,2,3,4,5,6, or 7) on their numpad. `aDelay` by default is 1020 but can also be defined by the user later.

Comment: @breadguy, I don't ask how they are calculated. I want to see the actual values.

Comment: @dyukha I am sorry I don't understand exactly what or how you want me to show you the values. I have included the source code above. The values of those variables change depending on what the user chooses.

Comment: @breadguy, What: values of `x, y, amToggled, aDelay` in the beginning of `click` function on any problematic program run. How: print it somewhere or copy values when your debugger stops there. I know that the values are not unique.

Comment: Wait, maybe I didn't understand the problem correctly. Are you saying that you enter the loop body, but only for `i=0`?

Comment: @dyukha I hope this answers your question. Sorry for the misunderstanding. `i = 0`, `x[i]: 241`, `y[i]: 910`, `amtToggled: 2`, `aDelay: 2000`

Comment: @dyukha Yes it doesn't appear to actually be switching elements to set the cursor position to the values stored in element position 1 instead of 0 after the first loop.

Comment: @breadguy You have an `if` that almost always prevents your loop from doing anything. I suspect you misunderstand what `clock()` measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, what happens. This condition is only (possibly) true for `i = 0`:

```
if ((te / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= (aDelay / 1000))
```

Why? When you finish to work with `i = 0` you update `st`.
In the next iteration you calculate `te = clock() - st`.
But computers are very fast, and therefore `te` is likely to be zero (or some small number, like 1).
In the end for `i > 0` `te / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is much less than `1.02`, and therefore you never enter the body for other vars.

Since you likely just want to iterate over positions with pause `aDelay / 1000`, just use `Sleep(aDelay)` instead of `if`.

In the future, post [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we don't waste time for other possible issues.